# Mobile CSS Code Problems

Tags: html, css, mobile, webkit

I'm trying to make a mobile version of my site. Here is the code for the "banner":

```
<center>
    <div id="banner">
        <a href="./"><img src="graphics/banner.png" /></a>
    </div>
</center>
```

And using this CSS:

```
#banner img a {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    color: #222;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

When I try it like that it won't work. Everything that was written apparently gets ignored, but if I remove the `a`, it works normal. But I need it to do that just if the `<img>` is surrounded by `<a>`. Why it won't work?

Comment: so i guess <center> is supported on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#banner img a` means "An **a** element contained in an **img** element contained in an element with the id **banner*".

You want: `#banner a img` if you want to select the img element.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's what I mean **:)**

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to have a comma between the HTML elements you want to apply the style to. Try `#banner img, a{
...
}` instead.